# No feedback after submitting a closed question for review

Tags: discussion, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

My question was closed 3 days ago for being off-topic

[Programming Exercises UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/143838/programming-exercises-ux)

I made the necessary changes in order to comply with the guidelines, following the feedback I was given. I haven't heard anything from a moderator since I submitted the question for review. Are there any steps I can take in order to draw attention to my question so it can be considered for re-opening? This hadn't ever happened to me; usually, my question would be opened again in a few hours since my edit.

Comment: This should be posted over on https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/. This site here is the Meta site for all of Stack Exchange; questions here should broadly apply across more then one individual site. Questions about specific sites belong on those sites' individual meta sites.

Comment: Your edit did send the question to the reopen queue, you can see as much in the timeline. Sadly, that's the most we can see as ordinary users, so either not enough people reviewed yet, or it was deemed to stay closed even after your edit.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any steps I can take in order to draw attention to my question so it can be considered for re-opening?

It *is* already being considered for reopening: [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/67189) is the review queue item. Unfortunately, the review queues are a bit slow on that particular site. Since a ♦ moderator voted to close, you could also [ping him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232).